# Udacity Android Dev Sunshine crash

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I recently started learning android dev via Udacity. I am currently doing the Sunshine Weather App. In midway of the course, when I executed the app, it crashed on Launch. Here is the code.

main_activity.xml -

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

MainActivity.java -

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

fragment_main.xml -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

ForecastFragment.java -

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forcastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh){
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Wed - Sunny - 87/10",
                "Thu - Snowy - 104/150",
                "Fri - Boomy - 78/67",
                "Sat - CYCLONE - 60/51",
                "Sun - Sunny - 80/20"
        };

        List<String> weekforecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
        );

        mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                        weekforecast
                );

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>   {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
// so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

// Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

The Above are the main files. If required I will add the codes of other files too.

I cannot figure out why the app crashes on Launch. Below are the logs.

```
04-27 07:33:10.709 9493-9493/com.example.android.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine/com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                                at com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivityFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                                                                                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:596)
                                                                                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
                                                                                at com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivityFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sunshine-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.sunshine-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
                                                                                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738) 
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34) 
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
                                                                                at com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

Can someone guide me in fixing this error and make the app functioning again? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `MainActivityFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public`... Did you do that stuff?

Comment: @cricket_007 I checked the error. And I am sorry; I did not see that. Although I fixed that, the app is still crashing at launch.

Comment: Is there a different error, then?

Comment: Oh Wait! Thanks for help @cricket_007!! I made a huge mistake not checking the error logs. Thanks for Help. My Problem got fixed!

Comment: Welcome. You'd be surprised how easily searchable some Android errors actually are. You just need to read the logs

Comment: I will make sure I read all the log messages from today! Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you rename the Fragment?

If so, you'll need to change the XML. Your error says the class mentioned at the line below in your XML cannot be found.

> MainActivityFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Here is what it points at

```
tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
```

Comment: Thanks For your Help. It fixed my Problem.